# Increase UISlider height without using image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

I want to increase UISlider height using color or any other way. I do not want to use image. I do not want to set setMaximumTrackImage & setMinimumTrackImage.
How can i implement this ?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to subclass, you can apply scale transform to the slider

```
slider.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0f, 2.0f);
```