# Increase UISlider height in Swift 3 without using transform

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I have a `UISlider` from the storyboard in my app. I'd like to change the "track" or bar-looking part to 2x its size and leave the marker/circular part at its current/default size.

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36663832/increase-uislider-height-without-using-image), they recommended using .transform, which I adapted like so:

```
    Slider.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2.0, y: 2.0)
```

The output is problematic, as it expands the Slider's marker 2x as well.

[image]

I am stuck -- is there a way that I can modify just the track to make it bigger? I have not found a good solution.

I should note that I'd ideally like to use the storyboard element rather than creating an image, if possible. I'd like to do it programmatically.

Comment: Have you looked through the `UISlider` documentation for anything related to the track size?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23320179/make-uislider-height-larger?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa
Duplicate ?

Comment: @robmayoff: I believe this does not answer. I came across this and receive `Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'trackRect'` when I use that code. Believe that does not work for Swift 3, but I am new to this so maybe wrong?

Comment: I have a complete answer if this is opened again -- you need to make a class and specify it in the storyboard and then it will run. That is where the answer from your question comes in.

Comment: I copied and pasted the code from that answer into a test project and it did exactly what was requested.